# How to convert from c3d file to csv

Tags: python, csv, numpy

Hi i have a project were the user uploads a .c3d file to be able to display the data on charts, so i am making it for when the user uploads a the file it gets converted into a .csv file so i can get the values but i am having no luck trying to convert from the .c3d file to the .csv extension.

i have used the following documentation http://c3d.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

but there much isn't much information on this out there

this is the following code i use to print the data:

```
import c3d

reader = c3d.Reader(open('file.c3d', 'rb'))
     for i, points, analog in reader.read_frames():
     print('frame {}: {}'.format(i, points.round(2)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The c3d library I suppose you use(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/c3d/0.2.1) includes a script for converting C3D data to CSV format (c3d2csv).

Comment: thanks, i'm not used to python, how would i able able to run that script if you could help?

Comment: to run that script you find where you installed it (e.g if you use anaconda maybe you should find it in anaconda/bin/c3d2csv). You should call the script from a bash shell

Comment: yeah i understand, but i mean when i run it i need to be able to add the file location of the .c3d file

Comment: you could try to redirect the standard output of the c3d2csv script with `c3d2csv ... > your_file.csv`